# PostgreSQL - CASE WHEN something THEN get data from different schema?

Tags: sql, postgresql

My situation looks like this - I'm working on postgres database, with ERP application with huge SQL queries and I can't even put this query here, but it is not the problem I only need an advice.

- I have query wchich gets informations about order number, date and so
  on.  There are to schemas g and h - they have same named tables, but
  with different data.
- In one table at schema g I have column wchich can be 1 or 0.
- Now i need to check in this query if this value is 0 - then i need to
  get data from table on g schema, and when it's 1 - from h schema.

Something like:

```
SELECT data FROM g.table
CASE WHEN data=0
     THEN leave it as it is
     WHEN data=1
     THEN get data from h schema
```

whether it is possible at all? Some function maybe or other solution? 
Thanks

Comment: you could  join the two table

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague, so my answer is too:

```
SELECT CASE g."table".data
          WHEN 0 THEN g."table".data
          WHEN 1 THEN h."table".data
       END
FROM g."table"
   CROSS JOIN h."table";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a structure more like this:

```
select g.*
from g
where g.col = 0
union all
select h.*
from h
where exists (select 1 from g where g.? = h.? and g.col = 1);
```